# Webaudio convolution not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I am currently learning about the webaudio api through examples and I stumbled across this little pen:

http://codepen.io/andremichelle/pen/NPPEPY

What I noticed was that the audio doesnt play in firefox until I turn the slider to the left. This means the convolution doesnt work because the supplied format is a wav? In the spec it says it is supported. I tried something though, instead of supplying a wav file I tried an mp3 instead and it works until. However this comes not without its side effects, because this time, as soon as I moved the slider I didnt get any sound.

So what is going on in firefox?

**Bonus Points:** I will create a bounty in two days, so anyone who can find out what the issue is, will be supplied with additional 250 points :)

Here some code:

```
var context = new AudioContext();
var audioElement = document.getElementById('player');
var carrier = context.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);
var convolver = context.createConvolver();
var dry = context.createGain();
var wet = context.createGain();

carrier.connect( convolver );

convolver.connect(wet);
carrier.connect(dry);

dry.connect( context.destination );
wet.connect( context.destination );

var mix = function( value ) {
    dry.gain.value = ( 1.0 - value );
    wet.gain.value = value;
}

var loadImpulse = function ( fileName )
{
  var url = "http://files.andre-michelle.com/impulse/" + fileName;
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open( "GET", url, true );
  request.responseType = "arraybuffer";
  request.onload = function ()
  {
    context.decodeAudioData( request.response, function ( buffer ) {
      convolver.buffer = buffer;
    }, function ( e ) { console.log( e ); } );
  };request.onerror = function ( e )
  {
    console.log( e );
  };
  request.send();
};

loadImpulse(document.getElementById('impulse').value);
mix(1.0);

function changeValue(string,type)
{
  var value = parseFloat(string) / 100.0;

  switch(type)
  {
    case 'mix':
        mix(value);
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the firebug console, I see that firefox gives the error

```
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://files.andre-michelle.com/impulse/factory.hall.wav"
```

So the impulse response wasn't actually loaded.  Hence the dry and wet sound the same.